# How can we view Android 2.3 browser remotely?

Tags: android, browser

How can I remotely view the android 2.3 browser on PC so I can debug the code?

Comment: There is no such verb in English as "_remote_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is too easy. Just use adobe shadow to remote android browser on PC. To know more just see this link... http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/

Comment: Adobe shadow only shows you what your site looks like it does not allow javascript debuggin :(

Comment: It is named Adobe Inspect now and it doesn't work for localhost :(